# Is Sebulba Force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-phantom-menace

Being Force-sensitive definitely helps if you are a pilot or Podracer and some of the best like Anakin and Luke definitely were. Furthermore, Qui-Gon Jinn, albeit probably exaggerating a bit, admitted:

> Qui-Gon Jinn: You must have Jedi reflexes if you race pods.

This can be interpreted as: If you survive long enough in Podracing, you must either have excellent reflexes equivalent to those of a Jedi or you must be Force-sensitive.

Now, in the Phantom Menace we see another top Podracer and very skilled pilot, namely Sebulba, so my question is: **Is Sebulba Force-sensitive?**

Comment: @RogueJedi It is related in that it does reference back to Jedi reflexes as a helping factor. But still different enough because it's looking for an answer regarding Sebulba specifically. Regardless of premise that leads to the question, this could still have it's own answer completely unrelated to the other question.

Comment: Hmm. Seems very dupey.

Comment: "_Being Force-sensitive definitely helps if you are a pilot or Podracer and some of the best like Anakin and Luke definitely were._" the question already begins with a different premise. The accepted answer on the other one also concludes that the evidence against the other racers was in the massive margin by which they lost. Sebulba stands out among the rest in that he "always wins", and even against Anakin it was very close.

Comment: It's a fair point. It would be better to strip it of the dupey content and ask why Sebulba always wins.

Comment: Sebulba just has fast reflexes. Qui-Gon was saying humans could only race pods with jedi reflexes. Other species would have the capability without force-sensitivity.

Comment: Luke wasn't a podracer. A good pilot, yes, but not a podracer specifically.

Comment: Voting to leave open. The potential dupe asserts that not every pod racer has Jedi-like reflexes. We cannot deduce from this that every pod racer does not have Jedi-like reflexes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Sebulba isn't (as far as we're aware) force-sensitive.

Per [Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars), his success is less a result of his species' naturally excellent reflexes and more as a result of his powerful podracer,  aggressive racing style and willingness to outright cheat.

> **Sebulba**
>
> *The reigning champion of the Outer Rim podraco circuit is Sebulba, an
> arboreal Dug, who pilots a souped up, overpowered orange racer.
> Although no one disputes that his expensive racer is fast, **the shifty
> Dug's winning streak has less to do with his piloting skills and more
> to do with his refusal to let rules and regulations got in the way of
> victory.** He is not above sabotaging a competitor's vehicle before a
> race and frequently uses illegal weaponry hidden aboard his own racer
> to distract or even bring down other pilots.*

---

You may wish to note that Qui-Gon mentions that they

> *["have Podracing on Malastare."](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html)*

Malastare is Sebulba's homeworld, suggesting that others of his species are similarly capable of the fast-reflex piloting required.

Answer (score 3):

### No sources confirm or deny, but there's no reason to suspect he is

I have not found any sources that comment on a link between [Sebulba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sebulba) and the Force, present or otherwise.

If our only reason to suspect that he might be is [podracing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Podracing), then [that's  not enough to go off of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111469/does-every-podracer-pilot-have-jedi-like-reflexes). The Force was able to given Anakin, a human, edge enough to go head to head against Sebulba and win. But that's already saying something because humans are specifically noted as not having quick enough reflexes to handle the sport. If Sebulba was Force sensitive as well, that would significantly lessen Anakin's edge.

Furthermore, having great skill in something isn't dictated by the Force. Han is an expert shot and pilot without any Force sensitivity himself. So lacking any works speaking specifically to whether or not he does, [we can pretty safely assume not](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127198/how-common-are-force-sensitives-in-the-star-wars-universe).